# Updating KeyVault Access policy with c#

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

Is there a way to update KeyVault access policy with C# SDK?

It is rather easy to do it with Powershell `Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy`, but I can't seem to find the same method in C# SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyVault PowerShell uses the KeyVault Management C# SDK - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.keyvault.keyvaultmanagementclient

Here is it's usage:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/ResourceManager/KeyVault/Commands.KeyVault/Commands/SetAzureKeyVaultAccessPolicy.cs#L268

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/ResourceManager/KeyVault/Commands.KeyVault/Models/VaultManagementClient.cs#L135

So, the answer to your question is no.
Having said that, I hope the above reference helps you.

Comment: Actually there is a way and your answer pointed me into the right direction. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.keyvault. If you edit the answer with the link, I will definitely accept it :)